# is it possible to convert string to jsx component? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement dynamic render of react-native-chart-kit where the chart type will be set in props.

I thought of making it this way

```
import { LineChart, BarChart, PieChart, ProgressChart, ContributionGraph, StackedBarChart} from 'react-native-chart-kit'

export function chart(props){
   return <{props.type} data={props.data} //props.type is one of the imported components
            width={Dimensions.get('screen').width}
            height={220}
            chartConfig={props.config}
            style={{
              marginVertical: 8,
              borderRadius: 16
            }} />
}
```

is there a way for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a simple string component (e.g. `h1` or `a`) then you could assign it to a variable e.g.

```js
export function chart(props){
   const Type = 'a';
   return <Type />; // React.createElement('a') should also work
}
```

In your case where you refer to a class however you might find it easier to import the entire library:

```js
import * as ChartKit from 'react-native-chart-kit'

export function chart(props){
   if (ChartKit[props.type]) {
       const Type = ChartKit[props.type];
       return <Type data={props.data} //props.type is one of the imported components
            width={Dimensions.get('screen').width}
            height={220}
            chartConfig={props.config}
            style={{
              marginVertical: 8,
              borderRadius: 16
            }} />
   }
   return null; // Or throw an error

}
```

As far as I'm aware there's no simple way to get the class definition reference from a string (aside from doing an `eval` which is bad practice).

Comment: No error. its just doesn't render the chart.
What is happening using your answer is that it creates new component without referring to the imported component.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. the import is not a component it's a component definition that is used to render a new component. That's how all other components work isn't it?

Comment: I am new to react but what I understood is that the component definition in the import are not invoked using both of your suggestions.